# Performing Statistics operation on field in Attribute table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, shapefile, attribute-table, statistics

I am working with the Shapefile consisting set of points. One of its field (let's call it X) contains numeric data, ranging from 0 to 1. In order to find out the average value of field X, I opened Attribute table, navigated to the field X and clicked with the right mouse on it. Showing me the list of options, the option Statistics is not active, meaning I cannot click on it.

It is a text field holding double. When I tried to perform some filtering using this attribute X, the operation looked like X >= '0.99' for example. But it worked, it indeed performed the operation correctly.

Has anyone ever faced this situation?

Comment: is it a text field that is holding integers?

Comment: @ed.hankins Yes, it is a text field holding double. When I tried to perform some filtering using this attribute X, the operation looked like X >= '0.99' for example. But it worked, it indeed performed the operation correctly.

Comment: You ***cannot*** do math on a text field.  You must first convert it to a numeric field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to create a new field in your attribute table and call it [Z] and make it float type,  then do a field calculate on it making the new field [Z] = int([X])

once you have done this, you can run the stats on the new float field [Z] and it will work.

you can never get stats on a field that is a string.  you will always have to convert it to int or float etc... to be able to get stats

Comment: In this case, a double (or single) float field appears to be more appropriate.

Comment: yes float is definitely more appropriate here, I corrected my answer to reflect it.